# My android app works on some devices while others from the same type can't work until doing factory rest

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, google-play-services, tesseract

I have an android application that's working fin in my tablet Galaxy TabA with android version 10, my application was tested in some other android version like 9,8.1 and 7. it all works well. after releasing the app to others, the app will not work on some devices that are exactly the same type "Galaxy TabA android version 10". however the application will work after doing one of these two options

- factory reset to the device
- debug one of these devices and adding a breaking points the application will work and the issue
  will disappear even after running the application without debug.

Both ways the issue will not happen again at all.
This is very confusing and really I have no idea why such behavior will happen, I really hope anyone can help me in this. for information I'm using OpenCV 4 in this app ,tesseract 4, and com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0:15.0.0

Comment: are you getting some errors while installing the app or your app is not working as intended after installing the app?

Comment: The app can be installed and is working but some functionality are not working as intended to be.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to find the source of the issue, the problem I had was the implementation of TextRecognizer in google-vision-API. TextRecognizer.isOperational() API always returns false, and therefore my program crashes after that. The difficult part was, the code was successfully installed in multiple devices since I implemented this API, and only after few months my app was published, so I totally didn't expect the issue to be from there.

Here are some links that suggest how to solve such issues.

[TextRecognizer.isOperational() API always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410777/textrecognizer-isoperational-api-always-returns-false)

[Google Vision API Text Recognizer is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570243/google-vision-api-text-recognizer-is-not-working)